# mysql query to find daily increase or decrease

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, window-functions

I'm new to mysql. I have a table as below. It has stock level for different SKUs stored every day. I am trying to write a query that outputs how many SKUs have increased stocks and how many reduced stock levels on a daily basis over a number of days. My main issue is finding the difference in stock levels daily between any two dates and classifying it as increase or decrease. The table does not store the amount of increase or decrease daily.  Any help/direction will be greatly appreciated.

Table:

```
+------------+---------+-------+
| Date       | SKU     | Stock |
+------------+---------+-------+
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1001 | 23149 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1002 | 29218 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1003 | 14827 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1004 |  8852 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1005 | 47362 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1006 |  3572 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1007 |  8744 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1008 | 22788 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1009 | 41897 |
| 2020-03-23 | SKU1010 | 28245 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1001 | 18326 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1002 | 23123 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1003 | 48501 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1004 | 44070 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1005 |  3160 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1006 | 46216 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1007 |  1620 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1008 |  3314 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1009 | 32254 |
| 2020-03-22 | SKU1010 |  1442 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1001 | 40992 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1002 | 31477 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1003 | 22976 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1004 | 26858 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1005 | 32397 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1006 | 37801 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1007 | 19530 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1008 | 35202 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1009 | 11723 |
| 2020-03-19 | SKU1010 | 21201 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1001 |  7449 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1002 | 10404 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1003 | 34944 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1004 |  5696 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1005 | 14732 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1006 |  9916 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1007 | 46623 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1008 |  6755 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1009 | 42848 |
| 2020-03-18 | SKU1010 |  5209 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1001 | 31777 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1002 | 36504 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1003 | 43737 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1004 | 27706 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1005 | 12099 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1006 | 39922 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1007 |  4897 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1008 | 14773 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1009 | 20108 |
| 2020-03-17 | SKU1010 | 40094 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1001 | 15459 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1002 | 39511 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1003 | 13586 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1004 | 29648 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1005 | 41381 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1006 | 27868 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1007 |  4220 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1008 | 22182 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1009 |  9079 |
| 2020-03-16 | SKU1010 | 33130 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1001 | 29597 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1002 | 41033 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1003 | 40937 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1004 | 34551 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1005 |  7283 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1006 | 40625 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1007 |  7935 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1008 | 30623 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1009 | 27591 |
| 2020-03-15 | SKU1010 |  7633 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1001 | 21712 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1002 | 11933 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1003 | 25913 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1004 | 33388 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1005 | 44811 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1006 | 10177 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1007 |  4748 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1008 | 48676 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1009 | 44767 |
| 2020-03-12 | SKU1010 | 33986 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1001 |  9156 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1002 | 48079 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1003 |  8815 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1004 | 15756 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1005 |  4446 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1006 | 40009 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1007 | 15591 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1008 | 12904 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1009 | 34635 |
| 2020-03-11 | SKU1010 | 20042 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1001 | 11811 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1002 | 26257 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1003 | 11387 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1004 | 30888 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1005 | 12192 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1006 |  5236 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1007 | 26115 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1008 | 34821 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1009 | 15294 |
| 2020-03-10 | SKU1010 |  3344 |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

**Output required:**

```
Date        Decrease    Increase
2020-03-10                10
2020-03-11         6       4
2020-03-12         3       7
2020-03-15         4       6
2020-03-16         8       2
2020-03-17         4       6
2020-03-18         7       3
2020-03-19         3       7
2020-03-22         6       4
2020-03-23         3       7
```

Comment: Imagine that the value for some SKU is absent for some date (please do not tell that this is impossible) - how this must be considered? both for skipped date and the next one.

Comment: sql version is 8.0.20 running on Ubuntu 20.04.01.

Comment: Please add this into your question text - this is critical.

Comment: if SKU is absent on a particular day, we can ignore it for that day.

Comment: Ignore? this is impossible. Does we can use closest previous value instead?

Comment: it will be ok to use the closest previous value instead.

Comment: One more. I see the hole for dates 20-21... Does these dates are NOT to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT `date`
          FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT sku
          FROM test ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT cte1.`date`, 
                 cte2.sku, 
                 COALESCE( stock,
                           FIRST_VALUE(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY cte2.sku 
                                                    ORDER BY cte1.`date` DESC
                                                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING), 
                           0) stock
          FROM cte1
          CROSS JOIN cte2
          LEFT JOIN test ON cte1.`date` = test.`date`
                        AND cte2.sku = test.sku ),
cte4 AS ( SELECT `date`, 
                 sku, 
                 stock,
                 COALESCE( LAG(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY sku
                                            ORDER BY `date`),
                           0 ) lag_stock 
          FROM cte3)
SELECT `date`,
       SUM(stock < lag_stock) Decrease,
       SUM(stock > lag_stock) Increase
FROM cte4
GROUP BY `date`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03f9c1d03d639ddfaf7ca0bbec8ff6b2)

If the row for some particular `sku` for some `date` is absent then the value for the closest previous date is used.

If some intermediate `date` value is absent (like `2020-03-20` and `2020-03-21` in the example data) then this date is absent in output too. It may be added synthetically with both statistic columns values equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each and every SKU appears every day, you can use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0) and aggregation:

```
select
    date,
    sum(stock < coalesce(lag_stock, 0)) decrease,
    sum(stock > coalesce(lag_stock, 0)) increase
from (
    select t.*, lag(stock) over(partition by sku order by date) lag_stock
    from mytable t
) t
group by date
```

We can use an additional condition to filter out SKU that have gaps:

```
select
    date,
    sum(stock < coalesce(lag_stock, 0)) decrease,
    sum(stock > coalesce(lag_stock, 0)) increase
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(stock) over(partition by sku order by date) lag_stock,
        lag(date) over(partition by sku order by date) lag_date
    from mytable t
) t
where date = lag_date + interval 1 day or lag_date is null
group by date
```